# Parsing Apache 2 Error Log with Grok Debugger

Tags: apache, apache2, logstash, grok, logstash-grok

I'm trying to set up a pattern in the grok debugger at http://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/

Input:

```
[Sat Aug 01 21:54:54.048805 2015] [:error] [pid 4384:tid 140066215139072] [client 192.168.1.1:62028] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: foo in /home/koan/websightdesigns/websightdesigns.com/ierr.php on line 3
```

Pattern:

```
\[(?<timestamp>%{DAY:day} %{MONTH:month} %{MONTHDAY} %{TIME} %{YEAR})\]\s\[:%{LOGLEVEL:loglevel}\]
```

What I have so far works, it outputs:

```
{
  "timestamp": [
    [
      "Sat Aug 01 21:54:54.048805 2015"
    ]
  ],
  "day": [
    [
      "Sat"
    ]
  ],
  "month": [
    [
      "Aug"
    ]
  ],
  "MONTHDAY": [
    [
      "01"
    ]
  ],
  "TIME": [
    [
      "21:54:54.048805"
    ]
  ],
  "HOUR": [
    [
      "21"
    ]
  ],
  "MINUTE": [
    [
      "54"
    ]
  ],
  "SECOND": [
    [
      "54.048805"
    ]
  ],
  "YEAR": [
    [
      "2015"
    ]
  ],
  "loglevel": [
    [
      "error"
    ]
  ]
}
```

So far, so good. However, the problem I am having is that if I try to add on to my pattern to get the next section, the `[pid 4384:tid 140066215139072]` section, I get a compile error no matter I try.

I've tried:

```
\[(?<timestamp>%{DAY:day} %{MONTH:month} %{MONTHDAY} %{TIME} %{YEAR})\]\s\[:%{LOGLEVEL:loglevel}\]\s\[%{PID:pid}\]
```

And:

```
\[(?<timestamp>%{DAY:day} %{MONTH:month} %{MONTHDAY} %{TIME} %{YEAR})\]\s\[:%{LOGLEVEL:loglevel}\]\s\[%{PID:pid}:%{TID:tid}\]
```

As well as other patterns, but nothing seems to be working. Anyone out there know what I might be doing wrong in trying to get `[pid 4384:tid 140066215139072]` into variables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After working on this some  more, the following pattern is now working for me:

```
\[(?<timestamp>%{DAY:day} %{MONTH:month} %{MONTHDAY} %{TIME} %{YEAR})\] \[.*:%{LOGLEVEL:loglevel}\] \[pid %{NUMBER:pid}:tid %{NUMBER:tid}\] \[client %{IP:clientip}:.*\] %{GREEDYDATA:errormsg}
```